# Rails: how to create Time object in specific time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone, tzinfo

My app is working in "Moscow" (+04:00) timezone. But sometimes I need to create time object by only local time (for example "01 may 2012 13:45") and name of ActiveSupport::TimeZone object (for example "Berlin": +02:00 in Summer Time and +01:00 otherwise).

For example if I get "01 may 2012 13:45" and "Berlin" as input I want to yield "2012-05-01 13:45:00 +0200" or "2012-05-01 11:45:00 +0000". I create following function:

```
def from_local_datetime(local_datetime, time_zone)
  offset = Time.now.in_time_zone(time_zone).formatted_offset
  datetime = case local_datetime
  when String
    DateTime.parse(local_datetime)
  else
    DateTime.new(local_datetime)
  end.change(:offset => offset)

  return datetime
end
```

And at the first look it works as I expected. But is it a best practice for this kind of task? May be in some situation It works with errors. I'm not definitely sure.

I would be greatful to any comments.

**UPD:** I think bug may occur about time when DST changing the time. For example 26 march 2011 was GMT+1 in Berlin time zone and `Time.now.in_time_zone("Berlin").formatted_offset` returns "GMT+1", but it would be GMT+2 in 27 march 2011. So if I call `from_local_datetime("28 march 2011", "Berlin")` before 27 march it returns `28 march 2011 00:00:00 +0100`, but If I call it after changing the time my function returns `28 march 2011 00:00:00 +0200` :(

Comment: I'm not understanding the bug.  Berlin during standard time (winter) is UTC/(GMT) +1.  That is, when it's Noon in Greenwich/Paris, it's already 13:00 in Berlin.  In the summer, Berliners set their clocks ahead of standard time, so when it's noon in UTC or Greenwich Mean Time, it's 14:00 in Berlin.

Comment: as you can see from code above I get current offset in Berlin timezone by this code: `Time.now.in_time_zone(time_zone).formatted_offset` (+1 if Time.now is `27 march 2011`). But I'm needed to offset in Berlin when there will be `28 march 2011` (offset will be +2).

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion method is the right approach.

With web sites, you should make sure times are stored as UTC in the database.  If you can get the UTC value out of the database, instead of the local time (or maybe you can set your web server's time zone to UTC) it won't have to convert the time from UTC to local time, when you are going to then convert it to the user's timezone anyway.

And, of course, you will have to store the user's time zone preference.

Comment: Please, see UPDATE in original quiestion

Answer (score 0):

```
TZInfo::Timezone.get('Europe/London')
```

Find the time zone

```
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html
```